# Get label name from product WooCommerce shipping class Id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shipping-method

I want to display product shipping class label(character) instead its id(number). I mean, as seen in the image below, I wnat to chage 0 to Free or flat-rage etc. How or where do I have to edit under the relevant code below? Can I be helped by anybody professional?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJAZH.png)

The relevant code is

```
if ($sale_carousel_items_content) {

      $carousel_items .= '<ul class="products" style="background:yellow; border:none; padding-left:50px;">';
    enter code here
          foreach ($sale_carousel_items_content as $item) {
        if ( isset( $item['product_id'] ) ) {
          $product = new WC_Product( $item['product_id'] );
          if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
            $countdown_container_id = uniqid('countdown',false);
            $target = explode("-", $item['target_date']);
            $carousel_items .= '<li class="row"><div class="img-wrapper col-xs-12 col-md-6">';
            $carousel_items .= '<a href="'.esc_url($product->get_permalink()).'" class="link-to-product">'.$product->get_image( 'shop_catalog' ).'</a>';
            $carousel_items .= '<h6>'.$product->get_shipping_class_id().'</h6></div>'; 
            $carousel_items .= '<div class="counter-wrapper col-xs-12 col-md-6"><h6>'.$product->get_name().'</h6>'; 
            // Short Description
            $carousel_items .= '<div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description"><h6>'.$product->get_short_description().'</h6>';
            // Sale value in percents
            $percentage = round( ( ( $product->get_regular_price() - $product->get_sale_price() ) / $product->get_regular_price() ) * 100 );
            $carousel_items .= '<span class="sale-value" style="background:orange;"><font style="font-size:15px;">특판가         </font>-'.$percentage.'% </span>';
            $carousel_items .= '<div><h5></h5>';
            $carousel_items .= '<div class="price-wrapper"><h5>남은수량: '.$product->get_stock_quantity().'개</h5>';

            //$carousel_items .= '<div class="countdown-wrapper">';
            if ( $item['pre_countdown_text'] && $item['pre_countdown_text'] != '' ) {
              $carousel_items .= '<p>'.esc_attr($item['pre_countdown_text']).'</p>';
            }
            //$carousel_items .= '<div id="'.$countdown_container_id.'"></div></div>';
            //$carousel_items .= '<div class="price-wrapper">'.do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id="'.$item['product_id'].'"]').'</div>';
            if ( $target && $target!='' ) {
                        $carousel_items .='
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            (function($) {
                                $(document).ready(function() {

                                    var container = $("#'.$countdown_container_id.'");
                                    var newDate = new Date('.$target[0].', '.$target[1].'-1, '.$target[2].');
                                    container.countdown({
                                        until: newDate,
                                    });

                                });
                            })(jQuery);
                        </script>';
                    }
                    $carousel_items .= '</div></li>';
            }
        }
    }
    $carousel_items .= '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Final update**

Use the following to get the term name (label name) from a product shipping class Id:

```
$term_id   = (int) $product->get_shipping_class_id(); // Get the shipping class Id
$term_name = ''; // Initializing

if( $term_id > 0 ) {
    $term = get_term( $term_id, 'product_shipping_class' );
    if( is_a( $term, 'WP_Term') ) {
        $term_name = $term->name;
    }
} 

// testing output
echo '<h6>'. $term_name .'</h6>';
```

So in your code replace the line

```
$carousel_items .= '<h6>'.$product->get_shipping_class_id().'</h6></div>';
```

by the following code block:

```
$shipping_class_id   = (int) $product->get_shipping_class_id(); // Get shipping class Id
$shipping_class_name = ''; // Initializing
if ( $shipping_class_id > 0 ) {
    $shipping_class_term = get_term( $shipping_class_id, 'product_shipping_class' ); // Get the WP_Term Object
    if ( is_a( $shipping_class_term, 'WP_Term') ) {
        $shipping_class_name = $shipping_class_term->name; // The label name (term name)
    }
}
$carousel_items .= '<h6>'.$shipping_class_name.'</h6></div>'; // Add to output
```

Tested and works.

Comment: Thank Loic TheAztec for your answer. Which part in the original script and how do I have to use your advise code?

Comment: Hi Loic TheAztec, I inserted your advising code in the original. But the template of carousel is broken as well as shipping class label does not displayed. Would you please look into the code again if you don't mind?

Comment: Loic TheAztec, It works perfectly. Sorry for the previous comment. You are really a professional indeed. Thank you very much^^..

Comment: @kjcheon The shipping zone is not available until the customer has defined his shipping address, after adding something to cart.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean. Thank you for your time.